# Login page of Blazor 8 is refreshing in a loop

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a Blazor 8 server application. I adapted the nav menu to a SFmenu from Syncfusion.

In `app.razor` I'm using

```
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

and

```
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

But when I request the page login, `login.razor` has a constant refresh.

What could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

In `app.razor` I have

[image]

Comment: What does login look like?

Comment: What does the "constant refresh" mean? Is it entire browser tab refreshing, or just "login" withing blazor app?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with just the default Blazor server template and narrowed it down to the HttpContext being null in the "Components -> Account -> Shared -> AccountLayout.razor" file.

```
 protected override void OnParametersSet()
 {
     if (HttpContext is null)
     {
         // If this code runs, we're currently rendering in interactive mode, so there is no HttpContext.
         // The identity pages need to set cookies, so they require an HttpContext. To achieve this we
         // must transition back from interactive mode to a server-rendered page.
         NavigationManager.Refresh(forceReload: true);
     }
 }
```

This keeps refreshing the page and does not seem to change it back to static rendering when refreshing. I found this merge request https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/51134 that has more details.

Currently the only way I have fixed it is by not using InteractiveServer mode for rendering.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the cause of this refresh by chance. I was testing `blazored.modal` and I checked some articles that reported that the solution for `blazored.modal` to work in .NET 8 would be the following code:

```
<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode. InteractiveServer" />
```

And it really fixes it, but as a side effect the login page remains in infinite refresh.

Just remove `@rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer"` from within the `<Routes />` tag and the login page will stop refreshing.

Comment: This is so stupid, but this instantly fixed it for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is to change the App.razor file, like in the template for global (not per page/component rendering):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp2.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I'm new here, so I couldn't add a comment to Sienael's post directly, but in my case, that solution helped me.

**BACKGROUND:** The answer above to remove the *@rendermode* option for Routes will address the refresh issue, however, I was previously dealing with another problem, which, depending on the kind of pages you load (in my case, it was on a component page where I specified @rendermode InteractiveServer), causes event handlers such as "onclick" for buttons on certain pages to not work as they should. In my case, adding the InteractiveServer rendermode option on the App.razor page addressed the button onclick event handling, but I later discovered this refresh loop problem after logging out of the app.

By removing the InteractiveServer option, I can confirm that the refresh problem went away, but the onclick event problem I previously had returned... I'm now convinced that I introduced this refresh problem after I added that rendermode to resolve that event handler problem on my other component page since I discovered it later.

After changing the @rendermode to call the method Sienael suggested, BOTH the Button event handling and the Login/Profile pages work as expected for me. Thanks, Sienael!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).